# dijit/InlineEditBox: How to set max characters per line

Tags: dojo, inlineeditbox

In Dojo's text editor (dijit/InlineEditBox) I need to set dynamically the maximum number of characters per line.

I suspect that "editorparams" could be used for that, but I can't find documentation or good examples about it.

Is it possible to set a maximum number of characters per line? If so, how?

Comment: can you post your js and html !

Comment: I think this is a Dojo-specific issue. I don't see that their text editor provides that "max characters per line" functionality, but I wanted to ask just in case. Here is [the text editor](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/InlineEditBox.html) I talk about. An here's its [documentation](https://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.8/dijit/InlineEditBox#editorParams). I use Dojo 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. `editorParams` should contain object with properties of editor, you're using in `InlineTextBox`. 
See snippet below. 
In this case editor is `dijit/form/TextBox` and its property `maxlength` is set to 10.

```js
require(["dojo/parser",
         "dijit/InlineEditBox", 
         "dijit/form/TextBox" ], 
function(parser){
parser.parse();

});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.9/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<div id="editBox" data-dojo-type="dijit/InlineEditBox"  data-dojo-props="editor:'dijit/form/TextBox',
editorParams:{maxlength: 10}" >123456789</div>
```

Comment: Very good information. So now I understand that 'editorParams' actually configure the properties of the editor that you have specify when instantiating an InlineEditBox.

And one can check which properties each editor have in Dojo's documentation.

Unfortunately, the editor I use doesn't have any property for "maximum number of characters per line". 

Also: I've checked other inline editors (apart from Dojo's) and they don't have such functionality for wrapping lines after a certain number of characters. The closest that I have found is the 'wrap' property of the <textarea> element.

Comment: Exactly - that's what `editorParams` are for. What editor are you using? `maxlength` is property of `<input>` tag, so it should work for all widgets containing this element in their templates.

Comment: 'dijit/form/Textarea' has also property `cols`, that limits number of characters per line, but it seems to be ignored when used in `InlineEditBox`.

Comment: Aha, good to know. By the way, the editor I'm using is dijit/Editor.

Comment: See this [discussion](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Limit-the-Number-of-Characters-Allowed-in-dijit-Editor-td1638066.html)